# Time in C# and Windows

Tags: c#, .net, time

I want to write a program that has to know the real time.
if someone changes the windows time, I don't want my program's time to change.
HOW???

Comment: Try synching with a time server on the web?

Comment: How long do you care about the time?  Using something like [System.Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) will give you a value that is not corrected for timezones, DST or anything else.  It will roll over periodically, has no meaning on any other system, and has little meaning after the next boot.

Comment: I dont want network and it's a long period

Comment: If you don't want to use the internet and you don't want to use the Windows clock then you're pretty low on options!

Answer (score 1):

If you're unwilling to trust the system time, you will have to get the time over a network. Find a c# ntp client.

Answer (score 1):

Here some examples:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1005/SNTP-Client-in-C

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5972/Daytime-Internet-Time-Service-Class